# Getting surrounding JS closure code as text

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the surrounding js code of the current scope as text. It's meant to be embedded in a live editor afterwards. Is that possible? In the worst case, it can go through Rhino.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no.  JavaScript does not provide a reliable way to introspect over variable definitions or the call stack.

`arguments.callee` and `arguments.caller` do provide introspection into the set of functions on the call stack as long as there are no recursive calls, so you can extract source code by walking that.  But it can be defeated by

```
function defeatArgumentsCaller(f, args, called) {
  if (!called) { return defeatArgumentsCaller(f, args, true); }
  return f.apply(args);
}

function f() {
  defeatArgumentsCaller(g, []);
}
```

When `f` is called, `g` will be unable to determine that it was called by `f` by looking at `arguments.caller`.

```
function g() {
  var fn = arguments.callee;
  while (true) {
    alert(fn.name);
    var caller = fn.caller;
    // defaultArgumentsCaller is itself, not f.
    if (!caller || caller == fn) { break; }
    fn = caller;
  }
}
```

They don't allow introspection over the set of defined symbols, e.g. those introduced via `with` or `catch` so any attempt to enumerate the available local variables at the `...` in

```
function f(o) {
  try {
    throw null;
  } catch (e) {
    with (o) { 
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

by examining the call stack and function source code will miss some defined symbols.

The call stack is also different from the stack of closures.  For example, in

```
function counter() {
  var n;
  return function (f) { return f(n++); };
}

counter()(eval);
```

`eval` runs in a context that has more symbols available than the call stack would suggest since `counter` is not on the call stack at the point `eval` is called.

Rhino allows access to the current scope as a [`Scriptable`](http://marianoguerra.com.ar/docs/rhino-1-7R3/org/mozilla/javascript/Scriptable.html) which exposes the `getIds` method which can be used to enumerate the names in the current stack frame, and you can walk up to higher stack frames via `getPrototype`.

Comment: I need to verify this. ampersand said, it gives the full text. If it doesnt I will check the Rhino way. Thanks to you too.

Comment: @mc007, You may not need a 100% solution, but that solution will fail for recursive outer functions.

Comment: +1. Great explanation and examples. For 85% of the code I write and read, `arguments.callee` and `arguments.caller` will work.

Comment: @ampersand, I agree that these are often ignorable corner cases.

Comment: Its ok with the current scope to me. I actually want to "tag" a range  of code - the current scope - and make them public on the fly. So basically once it got scraped that way, it goes to the server as template, customizable for an editor.  I will check this soon as possible, thanks guys.

Comment: Oh may be this is any relavant, I am using dojo and the google closure compiler, I saw there is a sort of C++ macro mechanic for conditional compiling. Its enough when it gets from there as well.

Answer (score 4):

The `arguments` object has a member `callee` that refers to the currently executing function:

```
function example(){
    console.log(arguments.callee.toString())
}
```

will output the full function definition. So, this is not just the inner code, but includes the surrounding `function(){...}` definition.

Comment: thats cute, I need to play with this way a bit. Thanks !

Comment: `arguments.caller` will go up one more level.

Comment: @ampersand, Many browsers do not have `caller` as a member of `arguments`, only as a member of the function.  In Chrome, `(function () { return (function () { return typeof arguments.caller; })(); })() == "undefined"` but
`(function () { return (function () { return typeof arguments.callee.caller; })(); })() == "function"`

Comment: @Mike. As said, I am ok with Rhino, so its all pre-cached and don't need to run in all browsers. But hey thanks again.

Comment: @MikeSamuel, thanks for pointing out that `arguments.callee.caller` is more reliable.